# Install-ContainerOSImage not recognized at AWS instance Windows 2016 Full Containers

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, containers

I launched new Windows Server 2016 at AWS using image Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Containers-2017.01.11 (ami-7a803d1a). After installing PS module ContainerImage I tried to launch NanoServer docker image by running:

```
Install-ContainerImage NanoServer
```

I get error:

```
Install-ContainerOSImage : The term 'Install-ContainerOSImage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
```

operable program. Here is list of commands of module **ContainerImage**

```
Get-Command -Module ContainerImage
CommandType     Name                   Version    Source
-----------     ----                   -------    ------
Function        Find-ContainerImage    0.6.4.0    ContainerImage
Function        Install-ContainerImage 0.6.4.0    ContainerImage
Function        Save-ContainerImage    0.6.4.0    ContainerImage
```

`Find-ContainerImage` returns `NanoServer` and `WindowsServerCore`
How to install image to local repository?
I am behind proxy and `docker pull` does not work even I configured environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

Answer (score 1):

`Install-ContainerOSImage` has been removed. [MS support answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc571caf-af13-45ed-a021-cfcfcf532645/the-term-installcontainerosimage-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-on-build-build-14385?forum=windowscontainers)

Solution is to copy (download) image file and install it using `Docker.exe`

Comment: Proxy Configuration:
To set proxy information for docker search and docker pull, create a Windows environment variable with the name HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY, and a value of the proxy information